# map an object item to new value - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a question. I have an array of objects, and I'd like to uppercase the id of each object in the array. I did it with these lines of codes

```
let x = [
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
]
x = x.map ( (a) => {return {
    id :  a.id.toUpperCase(),
    path : a.path
}})
```

but it looks like a bad approach, I mean if the object has more values I have to repeat them in the map.Is there any better approach to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to modify the existing objects, you can just update `id`:

```
x.forEach(a => a.id = a.id.toUpperCase());
```

Live Example:

```js
let x = [
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
]
x.forEach(a => a.id = a.id.toUpperCase());
console.log(x);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want to create *new* objects in a *new* array (what your code currently does), you can use ES2018's *rest property syntax*:

```
x = x.map(a => ({...a, id: a.id.toUpperCase()}));
```

Live Example *(writing to `y` rather than `x` to emphasize it's a new array with new objects in)*:

```js
let x = [
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
]
let y = x.map(a => ({...a, id: a.id.toUpperCase()}));
console.log("x:", x);
console.log("y:", y);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

To do it without rest property syntax, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let x = [
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
    { id: "anc",path: "kdsfjdklsfj"},
]
let y = x.map(a => Object.assign({}, a, {id: a.id.toUpperCase()}));
console.log("x:", x);
console.log("y:", y);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```